# How can I create an empty gRPC service for a fake connection?

Tags: go, mocking, integration-testing

I'd like to create a fake gRPC service for testing such that my main code won't break when it executes:

```
conn, err := grpc.Dial(addr, grpcOpts...)
```

I found a few examples (e.g., [1](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/basics/), [2](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/w9qr/unit-testing-golang-grpc-client-and-server-application-with-bufconn-package)) but it doesn't generate `addr` of this fake gRPC that  could use to pass into `grpc.Dial` method:

```
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":50051")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
 
    server := grpc.NewServer()
 
    pb.RegisterDepositServiceServer(server, &account.DepositServer{})
 
    log.Fatalln(server.Serve(listener))
```

I.e., it listens to a preconfigured port and creates a server without a real address. What I want instead is:

```
fakeGRPCService := grpc.NewServer(%random_address that I can either pass explicitly or it'll be generated randomly%)
config.service_1_addr = fakeGRPCService.addr
startCoreService(config) // where conn, err := grpc.Dial(addr, grpcOpts...) will be executed
```

Update: what I probably want is:

```
listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":50051")
server := grpc.NewServer()
server.Serve(listener)
```

Comment: You can use `net.Listen("tcp","127.0.0.1:")` for the server, and use `listener.Addr()` to connect from the test.